# How to make a script's Gizmo toggleable in the Gizmos menu in Unity3D?

Tags: unity

I've implemented **Gizmos** for a few behaviours, and I'd like to make them **toggleable in the Gizmos menu**, just like the built-in ones.

Is this achievable?

[image]

Comment: Normally, when your MonoBehaviour implements either [OnDrawGizmos](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDrawGizmos.html) or OnDrawGizmosSelected, it is automatically added to that list under the name of the MonoBehaviour (Under scripts instead of under Built-in Components). But as your image doesn't unclude a scripts section, did you take this image while also having the script that implements any of those methods? If so, I'm not sure why it doesn't show...

Comment: Oh, then nevermind. I wasn't at home when the idea struck me, so I couldn't test it. This picture is from Unity's site. Then it escaped my attention until now.